Printer Batch file gets the result "Unable to initialize device"
Hope you are doing well.
I have a Zebra 505 label printer for printing shipping labels.
We are trying to network the printer so all users can print labels from Netsuite.
Currently the .zpl files are not associated with a program on the user computers.
Netsuite is a clientless, cloud based program so we can't associate zpl files to that.
The instructions from Netsuite say to create a batch file and associate the zpl files to the .bat
I have the printer connected to a StarTech printer server.
I have the Zebra 505 installed as a printer in Windows using the Windows wizard where it asks for drives and I install them via a USB drive.
I can successfully do test prints from the printer properties.
Printer info:
print server ip is 192.168.88.238
printer server name is Networking_Print_Server_09E3C2
printer device name is Zebra Technologies ZTC ZP 500 (ZPL)
printer share name is Zebra505
Shared on standard TCP/IP port 192.168.88.238
Testing:
Ping 192.168.88.238 is successful
Test print from Windows printer properties successful
I have also run it using IP address in place of the print_server
Error when running batch file:
Unable to initialize device \Networking_Print_Server_09E3C2\Zebra Technologies ZTC ZP 500 (ZPL)
Is the spaces in the Zebra device name an issue?
Thank you for your help.
@echo off
setlocal

:: Set printer details
set "printer_ip=192.168.88.238"
set "printer_server=Networking_Print_Server_09E3C2"
set "printer_device=Zebra Technologies ZTC ZP 500 (ZPL)"
set "printer_share=Zebra505"

:: Set the text to print
set "text_to_print=Hello, Zebra printer!"

:: Create a temporary text file with the content
echo %text_to_print% > temp_print.txt

:: Use the print command to send the text to the printer
:: Note: You may need to adjust the printer name format (\\server\printer)
:: Note: changed %printer_server% to IP address
print /d:\\%printer_server%\"%printer_device%" temp_print.txt

:: Clean up the temporary file
del temp_print.txt

:: Keep the window open
if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit


probably not your problem, but you should always quote the whole path, not just parts of it: "\\%printer_server%\%printer_device%". When you print from another PC, you don't use the actual device name (which is unknown to the client PC), but the share name.
